# Making an asynchronous function synchronous for the Node.js REPL

Tags: node.js

I have a library that connects to a remote API:

```
class Client(access_token) {
    void put(key, value, callback);
    void get(key, callback);
}
```

I want to set up a Node.js REPL to make it easy to try things out:

```
var repl = require('repl');
var r = repl.start('> ');
r.context.client = new Client(...);
```

The problem is that an asynchronous API is not convenient for a REPL.  I'd prefer a synchronous one that yields the result via the return value and signals an error with an exception.  Something like:

```
class ReplClient(access_token) {
    void put(key, value);  // throws NetworkError
    string get(key);       // throws NetworkError
}
```

Is there a way to implement `ReplClient` using `Client`?  I'd prefer to avoid any dependencies other than the standard Node.js packages.

Comment: I do not know repl, but please check for promises, i normally use the q module to implement promises. With promises you can change your functions and make them synchronous. Maybe repl already provide promises.

Comment: Along with promises you can use generator functions to make the code synchronous style using `yield` keyword, running with `node --harmony` flag

Comment: You really don't need to write your own repl wrapper. Just run node without any script and it will enter repl mode (without needing the repl module)

Comment: @solick: Promises don't make functions synchronous. Promises still requires you to pass a callback. The only difference is you do it in the `.then()` function instead of the original function.

Comment: My REPL wrapper does some other stuff, like parse command line arguments to load the API access token, etc.  But yeah, it's not really relevant to the core of the question.

Comment: @slebetman because JS is asynchronous by design, promises are besides callbacks the only way to sort of synchronize as far as i know.

Comment: @solick: The words may sound the same but synchronizing asynchronous calls (calling one final callback after a bunch of parallel async calls) is very different from making a function synchronous (allowing it to return a value). You cannot make async functions synchronous in pure js (you can if you're willing to play with the event loop in C - check out fibres). But you can synchronize parallel async function calls (check out async.js).

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronously wait for stuff with the magic of [wait-for-stuff](https://github.com/ujc/wait-for-stuff).

Based on your example specification:

```
const wait = require('wait-for-stuff')

class ReplClient {
    constructor(access_token) {
        this.client = new Client(access_token)
    }
    put(key, value) {
        return checkErr(wait.for.promise(this.client.put(key, value)))
    }
    get(key) {
        return checkErr(wait.for.promise(this.client.get(key)))
    }
}

const checkErr = (maybeErr) => {
    if (maybeErr instanceof Error) {
        throw maybeErr
    } else {
        return maybeErr
    }
}
```